# Best looking texture mapping for characters (NPCs, Enemies).

Tags: graphics, hlsl

I'm making "dungeon master-like" game where corridors and objects will be models. I have everything completed, but the graphic part of the game missing. I also made test levels without texture.

I would like to know which texture mapping would be the best for a realistic look.

I was thinking about parallax mapping for walls and doors, normal mapping for objects like treasure and boxes.

What mapping should I choose for enemies, npcs?

I have never worked with [HLSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Shader_Language) before, so I want to be sure that I'll go straight ahead for my goal because I expect another hard work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping to use depends on your tastes. But first of all implement diffuse color mapping and per pixel lights. When that is working add normal mapping. If still not satisfied, add parallax mapping.

Even better results than the combination of normal and parallax mapping can be achieved using [DirectX 11 Tesselation](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tessellation.html) and displacement mapping. But this is much more GPU intensive and may not work on older hardware.